# Display function output live without Button press

Tags: swift, function, swiftui, state, simulator

My Swift UI code currently calls a function to display calculations upon a button call. I'd like to display the function's output without the button call (in other words, the function is "live" and constantly calculating anytime a necessary variable is changed). Basically, I'm looking to get rid of the button that triggers this function call calculation, and always have the function's display shown. It has default values so it should have info even before the user inputs or something is changed.

The first screenshot shows the code currently, and the second shows where I'd like the time calculation string to always be. Note: this uses a Create ML file, so if you're inputting this code into your editor, it's not necessary to have the model use to calculate. Any use and output of the variables will do and I've left some commented code that might help.

I'm thinking there might be a calculate on change of X, Y, Z variable needed here. I'm not sure the best way to approach this and would love any ideas. Thanks!

```
import CoreML
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var wakeUpTime = defaultWakeTime
    @State var coffeeAmount = 1.0
    @State var sleepAmount = 8.0
    @State var alertTitle = ""
    @State var alertMessage = ""
    @State var showAlert = false
    
    static var defaultWakeTime: Date {
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.hour = 7
        components.minute = 0
        return Calendar.current.date(from: components) ?? Date.now
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
    
        Form {
            Section {
                DatePicker("Please enter a time", selection: $wakeUpTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                    .labelsHidden()
            } header: {
                Text("When do you want to wake up?")
                    .font(.headline)
            }
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text("Hours of sleep?")
                    .font(.headline)
                Stepper(sleepAmount == 1 ? "1 hour" : "\(sleepAmount.formatted()) hours", value: $sleepAmount, in: 1...12, step: 0.25)
                
            }
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            
                Text("Cups of coffee?")
                    .font(.headline)
                Stepper(coffeeAmount == 1 ? "1 cup" : "\(coffeeAmount.formatted()) cups", value: $coffeeAmount, in: 1...12, step: 0.25)
            }
            
            Section {
                Text("Head to bed at: IDEAL TIME HERE")

            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("BetterRest")
        .toolbar {
            Button("Calculate", action: calculateBedtime)
        }
        .alert(alertTitle, isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Button("Ok") { }
        } message: {
            Text(alertMessage)

        }

        }
    }

    
    func calculateBedtime() {
        do {
            let config = MLModelConfiguration()
            let model = try SleepCalculator(configuration: config)
            let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: wakeUpTime)
            let hour = (components.hour ?? 0) * 60 * 60
            let minute = (components.minute ?? 0) * 60
            let predicition = try model.prediction(wake: Double(hour + minute), estimatedSleep: sleepAmount, coffee: Double(coffeeAmount))
            let sleepTime = wakeUpTime - predicition.actualSleep
            alertTitle = "Your ideal bedtime is..."
            alertMessage = sleepTime.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .shortened)
        }
        catch {
            alertTitle = "Error"
            alertMessage = "Sorry. There was a problem calculating your bedtime."
        }
        showAlert = true
        
        // IF TRYING WITHOUT CREATE ML MODEL, comment out all of above^
        // let alertTitle = "Showing calculated title"
        // let alertMessage = "7:15 am"
        
    }
    
    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this approach, where you create a `class BedTimeModel: ObservableObject` to
monitor changes in the various variables that is used to calculate (dynamically)
your `sleepTime` using `func calculateBedtime()`.

EDIT-1: using Optional `sleepTime`

```
class BedTimeModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var sleepTime: Date? = Date()  // <-- here optional
    
    @Published var wakeUpTime = defaultWakeTime {
        didSet { calculateBedtime() }
    }
    
    @Published var coffeeAmount = 1.0 {
        didSet { calculateBedtime() }
    }
    
    @Published var sleepAmount = 8.0 {
        didSet { calculateBedtime() }
    }
    
    // can also change this to return the calculated value and use it to update the `sleepTime`
    func calculateBedtime() {
//        do {
//            let config = MLModelConfiguration()
//            let model = try SleepCalculator(configuration: config)
//            let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: wakeUpTime)
//            let hour = (components.hour ?? 0) * 60 * 60
//            let minute = (components.minute ?? 0) * 60
//            let predicition = try model.prediction(wake: Double(hour + minute), estimatedSleep: sleepAmount, coffee: Double(coffeeAmount))
//
//            sleepTime = wakeUpTime - predicition.actualSleep  // <-- here
//        }
//        catch {
//            sleepTime = nil  // <-- here could not be calculated
//        }

        // for testing, adjust the real calculation to update sleepTime
        sleepTime = wakeUpTime.addingTimeInterval(36000 * (sleepAmount + coffeeAmount))

    }
    
    static var defaultWakeTime: Date {
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.hour = 7
        components.minute = 0
        return Calendar.current.date(from: components) ?? Date.now
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var vm = BedTimeModel()  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    DatePicker("Please enter a time", selection: $vm.wakeUpTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                        .labelsHidden()
                } header: {
                    Text("When do you want to wake up?").font(.headline)
                }
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                    Text("Hours of sleep?").font(.headline)
                    Stepper(vm.sleepAmount == 1 ? "1 hour" : "\(vm.sleepAmount.formatted()) hours", value: $vm.sleepAmount, in: 1...12, step: 0.25)
                }
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                    Text("Cups of coffee?").font(.headline)
                    Stepper(vm.coffeeAmount == 1 ? "1 cup" : "\(vm.coffeeAmount.formatted()) cups", value: $vm.coffeeAmount, in: 1...12, step: 0.25)
                }
                Section {
                    // -- here
                    if let stime = vm.sleepTime {
                        Text("Head to bed at: \(stime.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .shortened))")
                    } else {
                        Text("There was a problem calculating your bedtime.")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("BetterRest")
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the idea. I'm put this into my Xcode to try it out, but it's only showing the "default time" (current time) where it should be showing the dynamic calculation. I used the object creation. Could I request a couple more descriptions on where you've commented "<---- here"? I think I'm super close to understanding your idea. Thanks!

Comment: First try my code and make it work as it is. Then uncomment the calculations 
in `func calculateBedtime()`. Note, I have `sleepTime = wakeUpTime - predicition.actualSleep` **without** the `let`. 
To understand my answer you need to understand `ObservableObject` and how it is used in SwiftUI.
I cannot explain all this in the space of a comment in SO. There are many tutorials on this on the net.
You may also want to read Apple docs at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app  Since I don't know what code you are using it is difficult to advice.

Comment: updated may answer with using Optional `sleepTime` and updated the `Section` display, to show a message when `sleepTime` could not be calculated. To further debug your issue, edit your post, and show the code you are trying to use and where the problem is.

Comment: did my updated answer worked for you?

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for the continued answer. I think the ObservableObject is a good thing to try. I'll try it out for a couple more days and let you know; there are ways I've displayed variables dynamically before though, and it wasn't with Observable Object, so I'm trying to see if there's s simpler solution or something obvious I'm missing in the current code. Stay tuned. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm still `tuned`, any news on your progress?

Comment: It did work thank you! I selected it as the answer